# How do I keep my cashmere scarf from unraveling?

Tags: clothing, fabric

I just bought a cashmere scarf, which I really like. However, even out of the box, I think it will unravel at the edges. Is there a good way to stop this from happening? Should I just be super careful with? Should I stitch the edges somehow?

Comment: Close up picture please

Comment: If the scarf was ready made it probably has a line of fine stitching at the edge to stop it fraying. Post a photograph of the edge you are worried about...

Answer (score 1):

If your scarf is not yet protected, you can make a very fine stitching on the edge of the fabric.

This can be done on a machine or by hand.
A narrow zigzag stitch over the outer two threads of the fabric will work but be careful than the fringe does not get trapped in the machine.

Working by hand you can make a series of stitches over those last two threads of the fabric.

Work in (one of) the main colour(s) of the scarf. And with thin yarn which is almost invisible.

But I do agree with the people who wrote that it is not unlikely that the fabric already has a protection worked in.